# Conditional Pop up on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, popup

How can I dynamically display a popup, based on a checkbox, on a page when it loads?

Requirement:

- Application Object

  - Field - testchk which is a checkBox field.

When the Visualforce page loads, if testchk checkbox is not checked in the queried application, then display pop up with a checkbox and submit button. Else display the page.

Answer (score 5):

If you are writing javascript code directly on VF page in you can do something like:
Write it in end of your VF page.

```
<script>

if({!myObjectReference.myField}) // return true or false, also try {!myObjectReference.myField == true}
{
   dsplayPage(); // or do nothing
}
else
{
  displayPopup(); // popup logic is in this method
}
<script>
```

To show a popup [Jquery modal](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) dialogue can be helpful also [here](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2013/01/jquery-popup-window-tutorial-plugins.html) you can find required popup to show and its implementation.